# how to remove image files that are smaller than certain dimensions

Tags: rm, pipe

I have already found an answer that lists pretty much everything.  Except I cannot get it to work.

I use:

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f | xargs -I{} identify -format '%w %h %i' {} | awk '$1<300 || $2<300{print $3}'
```

What is needed to remove the output files?
I tried adding | rm at the end but an error shows that im missing an opperand.  I want all the files that the code above prints to be deleted.

Can someone please help

Comment: I think you can use rm $(find...$3}'). In other words, wrap the above command inside the parens in $() to use the results as an argument to rm.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for letting me know. I'll move it to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `rm $(find...$3}')`.

In other words, wrap the above command inside the parentheses in $() to use the results as an argument to `rm`.

Answer (score 1):

`rm` doesn't read filenames from input. You can probably do:

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -exec bash -c 'for i; do size=($(identify -format "%w %h" "$i")); (( size[1] < 300 || size[2] < 300 )) && rm -v "$i"' remove-files {} +
```

- You can use `-exec` instead of `xargs`.

The bash command:

```
for i
do
    size=($(identify -format "%w %h" "$i"))
    (( size[0] < 300 || size[1] < 300 )) && rm -v "$i"
done
```

- loops over all the input arguments (`for i`)
- gets the size and stores it in an array (that's why there are parentheses around `$()`: `($(identify -format "%w %h" "$i"))`
- uses shell arithmetic `(( ))` to do the comparison

Comment: What is `remove-files` doing at the end of the command here?

Comment: Should't it be `(( size[0] < 300 || size[1] < 300 ))`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yep, I was using zsh when wrote this, and carried over those indexes.

Comment: @Hashim it's `$0` for `bash`, which in this case will be used for reporting errors from bash (so if there's an error, bash would print `remove-files: ...`

Comment: @Hashim More about `remove-files`: [here](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690). In this case the argument is important not only for reporting errors. If `{}` directly followed the code, then `for i` wouldn't process all the files.

Answer (score 1):

The following works and is very fast.
Save to ~/checksize.sh and make it executable with chmod (`chmod +x ~/checksize.sh`)

```
#! /bin/bash

#find . -type f -exec bash -c ~/checksize.sh ;
echo ${@}
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    echo "\$1 empty" >&2
    exit
fi

size=($(identify -format "%w %h" "$1" | tr -d "()"))
#echo ${size[@]}
#echo ${size[0]}
#echo ${size[1]}
if [ ${size[0]} -lt 300 -a ${size[1]} -lt 300 ]
then
    rm -v "$1"
fi
```

Then change directory into the directory you want to remove the files that are too small from.

After cd'ing into the directory, run the following: `find . -type f  | xargs -P 0 -L 1 ~/checksize.sh`

It runs fast because it uses xarg's -P 0 which makes `xarg` run with the maximum amount of paralellity possible. See its man page for details.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need this way for current Bash, here is the modernized form for saving arrays.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for i in ./*.png; do
    mapfile -d " " -t size < <( identify -format "%w %h" "$i" )
    if [ "${size[0]}" -lt 1920 ] && [ "${size[1]}" -lt 1080 ]; then
        rm -v "$i"
    fi
done
```